# Access command line argument in scripts of package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have created a command in package.json file

```
"create": "ng g component process.env.page --it false"
```

Now I want to access the passed page argument in the above command so that user can pass the component name to the npm command

I am running the above command as

```
npm run create --page login
```

and this runs the

```
ng g component process.env.page --it false
```

so new component is created with name **process**.

How can I access the passed page (login) in my script?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the primitive [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) or [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) which is a lot more powerful

here is a yargs example

`const argv = require("yargs").argv;`

`let page = argv.page //get the page`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of npm run is:

```
npm run <command> [-- <args>]
```

So you need to pass `--` before your args. Your command should be as follows:

```
npm run create -- --page login
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const minimist = require('minimist');

let args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
    default: {
        port: 8080
    },
});
```

run with

```
npm run start -- --port=8090
```

args contains

```
args: { _: [], port: 8090 }
```